# CakePhp 3.6 emitindo mensagem de deprecated (Accessing data as a property will be removed in 4.0.0.)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Tenho alguns códigos em Php usando o CakePhp 3.6 que fica emitindo o seguinte alerta:

```
Deprecated (16384): Accessing `data` as a property will be removed in 4.0.0. Use request->getData() instead. - F:\php\frameworks\cakePhp\bookmarker\src\Controller\ContactController.php, line: 33 [CORE\src\Core\functions.php, line 305]
```

Um exemplo de código seria o abaixo:

```
$this->request->data['email'] = $user_data['email'];
```

O que acontece é que se for um `get` eu consigo resolver usando `getData('email')` por exemplo, mas se é um `set` já não sei como fazer, tentei algo bem esquisito como o seguinte:

```
 $this->request->getData('email') = $user_data['email'];
```

tentei também:

```
$this->request->setData('email', $user_data['email']);
```

mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Soei bastante, mas encontrei a resposta.

Está em https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#_withData

```
withData( string $name , mixed $value )
```

Então fica assim:

```
$this->request->withData('email', $user_data['email']);
```

É usado with... para configurar valores, não sei por que, não sei se isso é uma convenção.